# OpenGL window isn't opening

Tags: c++, visual-c++, opengl, glut, glew

I have code from the OpenGLBook (openglbook.com) which compiles, but does not load. I have absolutely no idea why it's not loading. The code is as follows:

**main.cpp**

```
#include "main.h"

/// Methods
/// -----------------------------

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Initialize(argc, argv);

    glutMainLoop();

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

**main.h**

```
#ifndef main_h
#define main_h

#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/freeglut.h>

#define WINDOW_TITLE_PREFIX "CHAPTER 1"

void Initialize(int, char*[]);
void InitWindow(int, char*[]);
void ResizeFunction(int, int);
void RenderFunction(void);

#endif
```

**functions.cpp**

```
#include "main.h"

int CurrentWidth = 800,
    CurrentHeight = 600,
    WindowHandle = 0;

void Initialize(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    InitWindow(argc, argv);

    fprintf(
        stdout,
        "INFO: OpenGL Version: %s\n",
        glGetString(GL_VERSION)
        );

    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
}

void InitWindow(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);

    glutInitContextVersion(4, 2);
    glutInitContextFlags(GLUT_FORWARD_COMPATIBLE);
    glutInitContextProfile(GLUT_CORE_PROFILE);</pre>

    glutSetOption(
        GLUT_ACTION_ON_WINDOW_CLOSE,
        GLUT_ACTION_GLUTMAINLOOP_RETURNS
        );

    glutInitWindowSize(CurrentWidth, CurrentHeight);

    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA);

    WindowHandle = glutCreateWindow(WINDOW_TITLE_PREFIX);

    if(WindowHandle < 1) {
        fprintf(
            stderr,
            "ERROR: Could not create a new rendering window.\n"
            );
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    glutReshapeFunc(ResizeFunction);
    glutDisplayFunc(RenderFunction);

}

void ResizeFunction(int Width, int Height)
{
    CurrentWidth = Width;
    CurrentHeight = Height;
    glViewport(0, 0, CurrentWidth, CurrentHeight);
}

void RenderFunction(void)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glutSwapBuffers();
    glutPostRedisplay();
}
```

When I compile and try to run my .exe with Visual Studio 2010, nothing happens at all.
The OpenGL window doesn't even open. Visual Studio acts as if it is running something for about 2 seconds, then returns to its normal state.

Comment: By the way, don't call `glutPostRedisplay` from the render function. If you really want a continous update (in your case completely unneccessary, like in most cases) use the `glutIdleFunc`.

Comment: Do you see any messages on the command line? Try running the executable directly and seeing what the command line looks like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
glutInitContextVersion(4, 2);
```

Does your current graphics driver actually support OpenGL 4.2? If not, then your window creation will fail. 4.2 is still rather new; try 4.1 instead.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't even think that may be the problem. Now I can get on to chapter 2 of the tutorial!

Answer (score 1):

Try debugging! Place a breakpoint on your main function and step through until something causes the program to exit.

As Nicol Bolas mentioned, you might not have a graphics card that supports OpenGL 4.2. Go on to AMD or nVidia's website and find out if your graphics card supports OpenGL 4.2. If not, then change the following line to whatever version your card supports.

```
glutInitContextVersion(4, 2);
```