# OpenGL working for one program and for another one it gives error: "X Error of failed request"

Tags: c++, opengl, ubuntu-12.04, xorg

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [OpenGL window isn't opening](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8356058/opengl-window-isnt-opening)

This question has not much to do with C++, it's just that code is in that language.

Was just playing around with OpenGL and pretty new with it. My OS is Ubuntu 12.04. I am able to run some basic programs.

Code mentioned in [this link](http://www.videotutorialsrock.com/opengl_tutorial/get_opengl_setup_linux/video.php) runs fine on my system.
Now when I started the written tutorial, the [chapter 1 program](http://openglbook.com/the-book/chapter-1-getting-started/) fails to load. It gives error as:

```
X Error of failed request:  BadRequest (invalid request code or no such operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  154 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  34 ()
  Serial number of failed request:  34
  Current serial number in output stream:  33
```

This is not a `glxinfo` problem. I have [fixed the problem in glxinfo and xorg](https://askubuntu.com/questions/175744/x-error-of-failed-request-badrequest-invalid-request-code-or-no-such-operation). My `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` is not giving any error `(EE)`.
I have also installed the packages like `freeglut`, `mesa-utils`, `glew` and so on.

Is there anything I am missing here?

Comment: Did you try to find out the operation on which the error is given, for example via commenting out code or stepping through with a debugger?

Comment: @Nobody, This program simply executes and creates an empty window. With eclipse, I put the breakpoint and it seems that it terminates at "glutCreateWindow()" function which is part of "freeglut_std.h"; but then this function is there in the other code also which is working fine. Is it a problem related to OpenGL version ?